# server conditional response not working on react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been having problems getting a conditional response from an express server for a react app.
Below is the server side code:

```
app.get('/api/checklogin', (req, res) => {
    var val = req.session.user ? false : true;
    res.json({auth: val});
})

app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            UserName: req.body.uname
        }
    })
    .then((user) => {
        if(!user){
            console.log('user doesnt exist');
            res.json({error: "User does not exist"});
            console.log(req.query.p);
        }

        if(user) {
            if(req.body.p !== user.Password)  {
                console.log('Password is incorrect');
                res.json({error: 'Password is incorrect'});
            }

            if(user.Password === req.query.p) {
                req.session.user = user;
                req.session.auth = true;
                console.log(user.UserName);
                res.json(user);
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Using Postman, I get a response, and it is dynamic, depending on the log in. But when I try making a call to the api in react, only the `false` response is gotten.

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import Login from './Login';
import Errno from './Errno';
import Add from './Add';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Footer from './Footer';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Profile from './Profile';

class Index extends PureComponent{
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLogged: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getData();
    }

    getData = () => {   
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/checklogin')
            .then(res => console.log(res.json(), "this sucks"))
            .then(res => console.log(res))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Navbar />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' exact component={() => <Login auth={this.state.isLogged}/>} />
                    <Route path='/add' component={() => <Add  auth={this.state.isLogged}/>} />
                    <Route path='/user/:id' component={() => <Profile auth={this.state.isLogged} />} />
                    <Route component={Errno} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </ BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default Index
```

Comment: The fetch you are making is using the default GET http method, and your server-side code is expecting a POST.
Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch on the correct usage of fetch to create a POST call.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to send the `session.user` object with the request in the options parameter of the `fetch` request in your react component.

[Using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

The following is just a guess as to the shape of the request body since we've not seen what session/user object looks like in your app.

```
getData = () => {   
    fetch(
        'http://localhost:3001/api/checklogin',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            body: JSON.stringify({ session: { user: 'someUser' } }),
            // add any missing options/settings you need for the request
        }
    )
    .then(res => console.log(res.json(), "this sucks"))
    .then(res => console.log(res)) // FYI, console.log is a "void" return so `res` will be undefined
}
```

If you share/check how postman is successfully making the request we can hone in on a more accurate answer.